# HttpWebRequest is caching even with AllowWriteStreamBuffering false

Tags: c#, .net, ios, xamarin.ios, mono

I'm trying to implement an upload progress bar on an iOS application. My current implementation does this simple trick:

```
using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream ()) {
    byte[] dataToUpload = this.DataToUpload;
    int dataToUploadLength = dataToUpload.Length;
    int uploadedSoFar = 0;

    while (uploadedSoFar < dataToUploadLength) {
        int toUpload = 8192;
        if (uploadedSoFar + toUpload > dataToUploadLength) {
            toUpload = dataToUploadLength - uploadedSoFar;
        }

        requestStream.Write (dataToUpload, uploadedSoFar, toUpload);
        uploadedSoFar += toUpload;

        this.SetUploadedRatio ((float)uploadedSoFar / (float)dataToUploadLength);
}
```

The problem is that the requestStream.Write() is instant until around 100KB of data is sent, then it becomes more logical and the SetUploadedRatio() method shown above is called like it should. When the file is huge, this is not really a big deal, though we can still see it takes some percent instantly and then start to percent slower. On slow connections, sending a 60KB file result in showing a progress bar that goes instantly to 100% but the actual upload is not completed at all, so we can't really display what's going on.

I did a complete showcase that exposes the problem (on Monotouch iOS), the link is available below:
https://github.com/rFlex/Monotouch-Upload-Showcase

This is where the interesting stuff is:
https://github.com/rFlex/Monotouch-Upload-Showcase/blob/master/TestUpload/Uploader.cs

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream just after the write? That might be the cause of the behavior you described.

Comment: Yeah I already tried with no success.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you set either HttpWebRequest.ContentLength or HttpWebRequest.SendChunked before calling GetRequestStream, the data you send will be sent to the server  with each call to Stream.[Begin]Write.  If you write the file  in small chunks suggests, you can get an idea of how far along you.